# Multiple MVC ViewModels Deriving From Single Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm unclear on the best way to have multiple view models that derive from a single model.

The model has the data annotations currently but we like the flexibility of view models as an abstraction layer and also to provide the flexibility of using the model attributes with different annotations depending on the views needs.

I've seen declaring the base model with MetadataType attribute to point to the view model that has the data annotations but this forces a 1:1 relationship when we need a 1:M (1 model : M viewmodels).

We aren't using mappers at the moment and leaving mappers aside, what would be the best way to manually accomplish having view models that include the data annotations that represent a single model.   Perhaps having the viewmodel derive from the model class, removing the model data annotations and then creating properties in the view model that mirror the model (but can't be the same name as that would shadow the model properties?) and have the view dictated data annotations on the view model property such as ...

```
    [DisplayName("Version Number")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public double VMVersionNumber
    {
        get {
            return VersionNumber; // VersionNumber is model property
        }
        set {
            value = VersionNumber;   
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't composition work better than inheritance?

```
public class ModelUser
{
  [StringLength(30)]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  [StringLength(30)]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelForSomeView
{
   public ModelUser MyUser { get; set; } 
   public string OtherPropertyNecessaryForThisView { get; set; }
   public string AnotherPropertyNecessaryForThisView { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where's the definition for type `User`?  And doesn't this defeat the purpose of a ViewModel, as (I'm guessing you meant to have the property set to `ModelUser` object) this wouldn't tailor the Model class at all.

Comment: Sorry, edited code a bit to clarify...

The goal of a Model is to model a business object. The goal of a viewmodel is to gather every piece of data for some page into one object. That's easily accomplished with composition. Are you trying to use your viewmodels for something else?

Comment: Composition is what I use now for ViewModels but this is tightly bound to the model in the sense that if I add a data annotation on the model (say required) then each view that uses that with a composition viewmodel must treat that field as required.  It would be preferable to add most data annotations on the viewmodel since the uses of the data will vary based on the views requirements.   Inheritance is more loosely coupled in my view and will allow the same data to be used in varying ways based on view needs.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem: If (for example) a user's first name is required, it's ALWAYS required. What scenario would there be where it wouldn't be required? If you separated out your models well, you shouldn't have this problem...

Comment: By the way, inheritance by definition is more tightly coupled than composition...

Comment: I agree, composition is more loosely coupled.  Thanks by the way to all for your input. I guess what I'm saying is that if one had a situation where one or more model properties had different uses across views, being able to specify the data annotations on the view models would be a nice design option. How might one do this is the ultimate question without resorting to custom server or client validations?

Comment: If they have different uses, they're different models or different properties of that model. You're skirting the idea the behind the concept of a model: It encapsulates business logic. If you're using the property in different ways in different places, that's a hint that you should have a different/new model.